# Как получить содержимое внутри []

Tags: python

есть текстовый документ с таким содержимым

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 96A7-B050

 Directory of C:\

[Games]               [Intel]               [PerfLogs]
[Program Files]       [Program Files (x86)] [Python27]
[Python273]           [radare2]             [Users]
[Windows]        
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  59 872 202 752 bytes free
```

как из этого получить массив содержащий названия папок

`[Games, Intel, PerfLogs, Program, Files, Program, Files (x86),  Python27, Python27, radare2, Users, Windows,]` ?

Comment: `re.findall(r'\[(.+?)\]', текст)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в лоб, то как-то так (с телефона пишу, может где-то отступы провалены. Andreymal опередил немного):

```
import re

f = open(FILE_PATH)
ml = []
for line in f:
    t = re.findall(r'\[(.+?)\]', line)
    if len(t) != 0:
       for el in t:
            ml.append(el)
print(ml)
```